# How to impurely modify a state associated with an object?

Tags: haskell, optimization, functional-programming, referential-transparency

In Haskell, I have a container like:

```
data Container a = Container { length :: Int, buffer :: Unboxed.Vector (Int,a) }
```

This container is a flattened tree. Its accessor `(!)` performs a binary (`log(N)`) search through the vector in order to find the right bucket where `index` is stored.

```
(!) :: Container a -> Int -> a
container ! index = ... binary search ...
```

Since consecutive accesses are likely to be in the same bucket, this could be optimized in the following way:

```
if `index` is on the the last accessed bucket, skip the search
```

The tricky point is the `last accessed bucket` part. In JavaScript, I'd just impurely modify a hidden variable on the container object.

```
function read(index,object){

    var lastBucket = object.__lastBucket;

    // if the last bucket contains index, no need to search
    if (contains(object, lastBucket, index))
        var bucket = lastBucket;

    // if it doesn't
    else {
        // then we search the bucket
        var bucket = searchBucket(index,object);

        // And impurely annotate it on the container, so the
        // next time we access it we could skip the search.
        container.__lastBucket = bucket;
    }

    return object.buffer[bucket].value;
}
```

Since this is just an optimization and the result is the same independent of the branch taken, I believe it doesn't break referential transparency. How is it possible, in Haskell, to impurely modify an state associated with a runtime value?

~

I have thought in 2 possible solutions.

1. A global, mutable hashmap linking pointers to the `lastBucket` value, and use unsafePerformIO to write on it. But I'd need a way to get the runtime pointer of an object, or at least an unique id of some sort (how?).
2. Add an extra field to `Container`, `lastBucket :: Int`, and somehow impurely modify it within `(!)`, and consider that field internal (because it obviously break referential transparency).

Comment: For the second possibility, you may want to use `lastBucket :: IORef Int` instead, and use `unsafePerformIO` to “impurely modify it”. Your JS code does not handle the fact that `__lastBucket` may be modified by an other `read()` call from another thread, hence have a different value at `if` and at `=`.

Comment: @Xicò of course, thanks! I wish I could hide that, though, because it is not part of the API. Also, what you said is true. But I don't need locks here, correct? Just store `__lastBucket` in a variable on the beginning. (JS doesn't have threads...). Edit: updated the OP.

Comment: Beware of threads if you decide to use unsafe tricks.

Comment: The first solution with the global map would need to use a weakmap instead, otherwise you'd get garbage collection issues.

Comment: Lift your operations into `ST`...

Comment: But @DanielWagner there is no actual state there in the sense that the function output doesn't change based on it, it is just an internal optimization. Wouldn't that make an ST API wrong?

Comment: @Viclib I don't know the technical definition of "wrong". =)

Comment: I don't know what is the english word, but I meant something additional that isn't essential, like a fifth wheel for a car... it is not "redundant"...

Answer (score 2):

Using solution (1), I managed to get the following design. First, I added a `__lastAccessedBucket :: IORef Int` field to my datatype, as suggested by @Xicò:

```
data Container a = Container { 
    length :: Int, 
    buffer :: V.Vector (Int,a), 
    __lastAccessedBucket :: IORef Int }
```

Then, I had to update the functions that create a new `Container` in order to create a new IORef using `unsafePerformIO`:

```
fromList :: [a] -> Container a
fromList list = unsafePerformIO $ do
    ref <- newIORef 0
    return $ Container (L.length list) buffer ref
    where buffer = V.fromList (prepare list)
```

Finally, I created two new functions, `findBucketWithHint`, a pure function which searches the bucket of an index with guess (i.e., the bucket where you think it might be), and the `unsafeFindBucket` function, which replaces the pure `findBucket` when performance is needed, by always using the last accessed bucket as the hint:

```
unsafeFindBucket :: Int -> Container a -> Int
unsafeFindBucket findIdx container = unsafePerformIO $ do 
    let lastBucketRef = __lastAccessedBucket contianer
    lastBucket       <- readIORef lastBucketRef
    let newBucket     = findBucketWithHint lastBucket findIdx container
    writeIORef lastBucketRef newBucket
    return $ newBucket
```

With this, `unsafeFindBucket` is technically a pure function with the same API of the original `findBucket` function, but is an order of magnitude faster in some benchmarks. **I have no idea how safe this is and where it could cause bugs.** Threads are certainly a concern.

Comment: In this case it probably doesn't matter, as the value is only a cache, but in general it's safer and somewhat more idiomatic to use [`atomicModifyIORef`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-IORef.html#v:atomicModifyIORef).

Answer (score 2):

<sup>(This is more an extended comment than an answer.)</sup>

First I'd suggest to check if this isn't a case of [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Program_optimization&oldid=677554019#When_to_optimize). After all, *O(log n)* ins't that bad.

If this part is indeed performance-critical, your intention is definitely valid. The usual warning for `unsafePerformIO` is "use it only if you know what you're doing", which you obviously do, and it can help to make things pure and fast at the same time.
Be sure that you follow all [the precautions in the docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html#v:unsafePerformIO), in particular setting the proper compiler flags (you might want to use [the `OPTIONS_GHC` pragma](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.4/docs/html/users_guide/ch04s02.html#source-file-options)).

Also make sure that the `IO` operation is thread safe. The easiest way to ensure that is to use `IORef` together with [`atomicModifyIORef`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-IORef.html#v:atomicModifyIORef).

The disadvantage of an internal mutable state is that the performance of the cache will deteriorate if it's accessed from multiple threads, if they lookup different elements.

One remedy would be to explicitly thread the updated state instead of using the internal mutable state. This is obviously what you want to avoid, but if your program is using monads, you could just add another monadic layer that'd internally keep the state for you and expose the lookup operation as a monadic action.

Finally, you could consider using [splay trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree) instead of the array. You'd still have (amortized) *O(log n)* complexity, but their big advantage is that by design they move frequently accessed elements near the top. So if you'll be accessing a subset of elements of size *k*, they'll be soon moved to the top, so the lookup operations will be just *O(log k)* (constant for a single, repeatedly accessed element). Again, they update the structure on lookups, but you could use the same approach with `unsafePerformIO` and atomic updates of `IORef` to keep the outer interface pure.

Comment: Edward Kmett has been working on some crazy tree-of-vector structures with lots of unsafe stuff that might work well for this, especially if modifications are also needed.

Comment: @viclib, you'll have to dig around in GitHub/ekmett, and look for recent stuff there. I'm not sure what's actually been released yet.